# Should I be concerned that latest Windows update added 4M new files and how to see them?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-update

I am doing full scans with Windows Defender of my Windows 10 desktop computer while it is sitting idle after work - once of twice a week. After each scan I save the statistics. For the last year the typical numbers were

```
~15.000.000 files scanned
scan lasted for ~4 hours
no threats found
```

I installed mid/beginning-January.2021 Windows updates (after delaying for some week or weeks) and now the latest Windows Defender full scan reports that ~19.000.000 files have been scanned in ~5 hours. No threat found. It certainly raises concern.

Should I be cautious about this? Is there information about number of files added in beginning/mid-January.2021 update? Is it possible to check (see the names, location and possibly, certification) the newly added files by Windows update?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I be cautious about this? Is there information about number of
> files added in beginning/mid-January.2021 update?

Windows Defender does not do excessive scanning of Windows 10 Updates. I do not see a concern here.

I have been running Windows 10 for 6 years now including all Feature Updates. Defender does not spend excessive time on updates.

See if you have a Windows.old file (Windows Explorer). This can be removed if Windows is running well.  Use Admin Tools, Disk Cleanup, Clean up System Files. Make sure you check off all items to be cleaned up. This will reduce the number of files scanned in a complete full scan.

Windows Defender does not report on files added by updates - many files may just be changes or replacements. Windows Update History will tell you what updates have been applied but not what individual files.

If I do a Defender scan, I use Quick Scan because Defender is monitoring all incoming activity as it happens. Make sure Smart Screen and like settings are enabled.

For about a year now, Windows Defender includes EMET tamper protection (Enhanced Mitigation Experience Toolkit). This is excellent added protection.

So you may be able to reduce your full scans without harm.